# IIS10 UrlRewrite Canonical Rule with Multiple Domains

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module, canonicalization

I am using the DNN CMS that allows multiple portals (many websites) under 1 IIS website. In this situation I cannot use the standard canonical rule below because I have multiple bindings for different domains but am getting errors on Google search console because I don't have a canonical rule. How can I modify my rule to account for the multiple domains?

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain1\.com$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)\.mydomain1\.com$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydomain1.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

If in my bindings I had:

```
www.mydomain1.com
mydomain1.com
www.exampledomain.com
exampledomain.com
www.thirddomain.com
thirddomain.com
```

I would like to set the www. versions of all my domains as the canonical target but each domain should have it's own not 1 globally.

Is it just a matter of adding more input's to that rule? IE:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^thirddomain\.com$" negate="true" />
```

----- ADDITIONAL INFO --------

```
In one rule I need requests to 
mydomain1.com sent to www.mydomain1.com
exampledomain.com sent to www.example.com
thirddomain.com sent to www.thirddomain.com
```

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. do you want to match multiple domains in one rule at the same time? If so, you only need to write a regular expression for the server variable {HTTP_HOST} in the condition that can match multiple domains at the same time. If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: Hello @samwu i've added an example to the post that hopefully explains it better. I do need this all in 1 rule.

Comment: One url rewrite cannot meet your needs, you need to create two rules, one for redirection and one for exampledomain.com redirection.